# Looping through an Object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want to loop through an object array and get `id, category` and `name` from it.
Here is my php code. which is getting xml content from a server with a cURL request and then converting it to object array. I don't know how to loop through it and get all the values i want.

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://wingz.info/daas3b/search?q=word&top=&user=xxxx&pwd=xxxx";
    $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            ob_start();
            curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
            $response = ob_get_clean();
            ob_end_clean();
    $response_array = @simplexml_load_string($response);
```

And the Object array is given below.

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => search
        )

    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 435
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => give
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 436
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => verb
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 437
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => noun
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 438
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => person
                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 439
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => adjective
                )

            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 440
                        )

                    [category] => word
                    [name] => adverb
                )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should list out the info you were asking for, and hopefully show you a bit about traversing the SimpleXML objects:

```
// Get the list of objects from your XML content
$objects_array = $response_array->content;

// Loop through all of the objects
foreach($objects_array as $xml_object) {
    echo '<br />' . xml_object->name; // The name
    echo '<br />' . xml_object->category; // The category

    $attributes = xml_object->attributes();
    echo '<br />' . $attributes['id']; // The id
}
```

Let me know if there was a problem and I'll edit this answer.

Edit: If it's not certain that each object will have an id/name/category: then the following, more robust code:

```
$objects_array = $response_array->content;

// Loop through all of the objects
foreach($objects_array as $xml_object) {
    echo '<br />' . (isset(xml_object->name) ? xml_object->name : ''); // The name
    echo '<br />' . (isset(xml_object->category) ? xml_object->category : ''); // The category

    $attributes = xml_object->attributes();
    echo '<br />' . (isset($attributes['id']) ? $attributes['id'] : ''); // The id
}
```

For more info on working with SimpleXML objects, check out https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php.

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$xml_object' (T_VARIABLE) on line 15

Comment: Ah sorry, edited now to change "$objects_array-> as" to "$objects_array as"

Comment: Robust version done in response to "J. A. Streich's" robust code

Comment: Thanks man you help me a lot. Thank you very much.@Hiphop03199

Answer (score 1):

```
// loop through
foreach($response_array->content as $thing)
{
  // get the id.
  $attrs = $thing->attributes();
  $id = $attrs[id];

  // check for and get the category
  if(isset($thing->category))
  {
    $category = $thing->category;
  }
  else
  {
    $category = '';
  }

  // check for and get the name.
  if(isset($thing->name))
  {
    $name = $thing->name;
  }
  else
  {
    $name = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't the 'id' and 'name' properties stored at different levels? Also: good work checking if they are set/providing default values, but might be cleaner to do with ternary: "$name = isset($thing->name) ? $thing->name : ''; ". A matter of personal preference though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah the id is in attributes... hold on I'll edit...  The ternary `:?` operator is one I use in real code, but often try to avoid when posting answers as it obfuscates the code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. It helps alot.@J.A.Streich